# Android EditText and VirtualKeyboard

Tags: android

i have an EditText ,it is located at the bottom of the screen ,when user touch on the edittext virtual keyboard is visible and hide the EditText, found on Motorolla , all other device it's working fine

```
            <EditText  android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/Edittext_Report" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="270dp" android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:maxLength="1000" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: It should auto-adapt to bring the editText up above the keyboard. Maybe its a Motorola bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use
>   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>   to your tag in the AndroidManifest.xml
>   file.

For Instance:

```
  < activity 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|stateVisible"   
    . . . >
```